# Inheriting a struct and all its content from a different class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, struct

I have been trying to make monopoly for a project that I have to do. The assignment requires me to use multiple classes and to use inheritance. I have 3 classes, player_properties, game_board and running. The main is in running. game_board contains a struct to initialise all the contents of the game board. player_properties contains a struct and it initialises all the properties attributed to the players. I want to inherit all of the properties of the structs to my running class and continue using them and make all the running of the game from the running class. Following is the code:

```
using namespace std;

struct player
    {

        string piece;
        int location;
        int money;
        int lost;
        int houses;
        int hotels;
    };
class player_properties 
{
public:
        player *players;
    int num_players;
    void assign();//alloting the requirements to the palyers and to the board

};
void player_properties::assign()
{
        //omitted some code to shorten code
        //assigning the players properties
            cin>>ch;
            piecetaken[ch]=1;
            players[i].piece=pieces[ch];
            players[i].location=0;
            players[i].lost=0;
            players[i].money=1500;
            players[i].hotels=0;
            players[i].houses=0;

        }



    }

using namespace std;

struct board_properties
{
    string name;
    int name_length;
    int board_location;
    string player;
    int price;
    int owner_id;
    int houses_owned;
    int hotels_owned;
    int piece_length;


};
class game_board

{
public:
               board_properties *b_properties
        void assigngb();//alloting the requirements to the palyers and to the board
};
void game_board::assigngb()//alloting the requirements to the palyers and to the board
{
        b_properties=new board_properties[40];

        for ( int j=0;j<40;j++)
        {
            b_properties[j].board_location=j;
            b_properties[j].owner_id=10;
            b_properties[j].houses_owned=0;
            b_properties[j].hotels_owned=0;
            b_properties[j].piece_length=0;
        }

}


#include "game_board.cpp"
#include "player_properties.cpp"
using namespace std;

class running :public game_board, public player_properties
{
    public:
    int pos_ch;
    int num_players_playing;
    void position();// to see the position of the player
};

void running::position()
{
    cout<<players[1].piece<<endl; //does not work, core dump since not initialised  
        //some other running code

}


int main()
{

    running rn;
    rn.position();
    player_properties p;
    p.assign();

    game_board gb;
    gb.assigngb();

}
```

When I try to use the classes, the player_properties and the game_board run, they initialise the variables, but when I come back to the running function, the values are not accessible. the line payers[1] gives a core dump since it says that players[1] cannot be accessed and does not exist.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem? What do you mean by "not accessible" and "uninitialized"? Can you post some output or errors?

Comment: #include "game_board.cpp"
#include "player_properties.cpp" -- Don't do this. If it contains definitions of data & functions, a cpp file should only ever be seen ONCE by the compiler. If it just contains declarations, it's called a *header* and should have the extension .h

Comment: Also unless it's in your 'omitted' section, it doesn't look like you're ever dynamically allocating memory for your `players` array, which would cause a crash when trying to access it.

Comment: Would i have to allocate again in the running class as i do dynamically allocate the players and the board_properties in game_board and player_properties?